# Upload a file with PUT on nodeJS problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, forms

I can't understand why this code doesn't work with PUT method and only works with POST

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function(){
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        uploadProgress(evt);
    }, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      console.log('down');
    }, false);
    return xhr;
    },
    url : 'upload',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(textStatus);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception){
        alert("error --'");
    }
});
```

When on `type` I have **POST**, uploading works, but it's doesn't works with PUT :X

And there is a way to upload file via **PUT** without submitting a form?

Because code like that doesn't works:

```
$('#file-input').on('change', prepareUpload);

var files;

function prepareUpload(event){
    files = event.target.files;
    $.each(files, function(key, value){
        data.append(key, value);
    });

    $.put(
        $(this).parent().attr('action'),
        data,
        onAjaxSuccess_s
    )
}
```

Comment: That depends on how your sever is setup up. But a `PUT` with the url `/upload` does not make much sense. The url used with the `PUT` request is the url where the resource should be saved. So for a `jpg` a put would look like `/uploads/test.jpg`. ([PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest))

Comment: Hello @t.niese! I think I have a good configuration of my nodeJS server, and on all examples that I can find I always see that type of url. All information is on a request variable.
But I will analyze your suggestion.

Comment: Without knowing your server code it is not possible to tell you why the `PUT` method is not accepted. The Specs are clear about the difference between `POST` and `PUT` `[...]The URI in a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed entity. [...]In contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.[...]`. So `PUT upload` is wrong.

Comment: @t.niese Hello! I tested your suggestion, and 'test.png' is only a string, doesn't have any parameters
`router.param('param1', function(req, res, next, param1){
   console.log(param1); //return 'test.png'
   req.param1 = param1;
     next();
 });`

Comment: @t.niese I need to receive something like that: ( console.log(req.files); )
`{ files:
   { fieldName: 'files',
     originalFilename: 'web.png',
     path: 'C:\\Users\\Ivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\6264-1a629s8.png',
     headers:
      { 'content-disposition': 'form-data; name="files"; filename="web.png"',
        'content-type': 'image/png' },
     ws: [ .too long code .],
     size: 13998,
     name: 'web.png',
     type: 'image/png' } }`